# Cyclotomic Polynomial and Isomorphic rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

**Setup.** Here are the objects we are going to work with:

- $m\geq 1$ denotes an integer and $\Phi_m(X)$ the $m$-th cyclotomic polynomial
- $P=p^e$ is the power of a prime number $p$ not dividing $m$

It is well-known that $\Phi_m(X)\in\mathbb F_p[X]$ factors into distinct irreducible polynomials $f_1,\dots, f_n\in\mathbb F_p[X]$, all of which are of the same degree $d$ equalling the multiplicative order of $p\in\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$. We can lift each $f_i$ to an element $F_i\in(\mathbb Z/P\mathbb Z)[X]$ so that $\Phi_m(X)\in(\mathbb Z/P\mathbb Z)[X]$ is the product of the $F_i$.

**Goal.** My goal is to prove that the quotient rings $(\mathbb Z/P\mathbb Z)[X]/(F_i)$ are all isomorphic.

**My progress.** I can prove it in case $P=p$. For this, let $R_i:=\mathbb F_p[X]/(f_i)$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. We can write $R_1=\mathbb F_p[\zeta]$ with $\zeta:=X+(f_1)\in R_1$. Consider next the group $G:=\langle p\rangle\leq (\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times$. The quotient group $(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times/G$ will contain $n$ elements, say $a_1G,\dots,a_nG$. We can order the $a_i$ in such a way that for every $1\leq i\leq n$, the $d$ zeros of $f_i$ are given precisely by the elements of $a_iG$. We then consider the ring morphism
$$\mathbb F_p[X]\ni f\mapsto f(\zeta^{a_i})\in R_1.$$

Its kernel equals $(f_i)$, hence we get an injective ring morphism
$R_i\to R_1$; it is necessarily bijective because all the $R_i$ contain $p^d$ elements.

**Where I am stuck.** It is now unclear to me how I can get the result for the general case. The proof above doesn't work here since we won't work over a field.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: You should not use $n$ as both the exponent of $p$ in $P$ and as the number of irreducible factors of $\Phi_m(X) \bmod p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it simplest to think about what is going on here by using the $p$-adic numbers.  The advantage of this is that it bypasses the ugly nature of rings modulo $p^k$ for $k > 1$ (as you note, $\mathbf Z/p^k\mathbf Z$ is no longer a field, or even a domain) but you can *recover* what's happening mod $p^k$ from what's happening $p$-adically by reducing modulo $p^k$ after working things out in the $p$-adic setting.

Instead of lifting the mod $p$ factorization of $\Phi_m(X)$ up to modulus $P$, let's go all the way to a $p$-adic factorization: in $\mathbf Z_p[X]$,
$$
\Phi_m(X) = F_1(X)\cdots F_n(X),
$$
where $F_i(X)$ is monic in $\mathbf Z_p[X]$ (here and below, $\mathbf Z_p$ is the $p$-adic integers, *not* the integers mod $p$) and $F_i(X) \bmod p = f_i(X)$ in $\mathbf F_p[X]$ (note $\mathbf F_p = \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z \cong \mathbf Z_p/p\mathbf Z_p$ in a canonical way). Note I am *redefining* your notation $F_i(X)$ to be the $p$-adic lifting of $f_i(X)$ in the $p$-adic factorization of $\Phi_m(X)$.

Because $F_i(X)$ is irreducible mod $p$, $F_i(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbf Z_p[X]$ (and $\mathbf Q_p[X]$).  We have $\deg(F_i) = \deg(f_i) = d$.

Let $r_i$ be a root of $F_i(X)$. Since $F_i(X) \bmod p$ is irreducible of degree $d$, $\mathbf Q_p(r_i)$ is the degree-$d$ unramified extension of $\mathbf Q_p$. Since $\mathbf Q_p$ has one unramified extension of each degree, the fields $\mathbf Q_p(r_i)$ are the same for all $i$. Moreover, because a root of $F_i(X) \bmod p$ has degree $d$ over $\mathbf F_p$, the ring of integers of $\mathbf Q_p(r_i)$ is $\mathbf Z_p[r_i]$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z_p[X]/(F_i(X))$.  Thus the rings $\mathbf Z_p[X]/(F_i(X))$ for all $i$ are isomorphic to each other: they're all isomorphic to the ring of integers of the degree-$d$ unramified extension of $\mathbf Q_p$.

Now let's descend from an isomorphism of $p$-adic rings to an isomorphism of rings modulo $p^k$ for each $k \geq 1$. When two rings $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic, a ring isomorphism $A \to B$ induces a ring isomorphism $A/p^kA \to B/p^kB$ for all $k \geq 1$. So a ring isomorphism $\mathbf Z_p[X]/(F_i(X)) \to \mathbf Z_p[X]/(F_j(X))$ induces a ring isomorphism between both sides modulo $p^k$. We have
$$
\mathbf Z_p[X]/(F_i(X),p^k) \cong (\mathbf Z_p/p^k\mathbf Z_p)[X]/(F_{i,k}(X)) \cong (\mathbf Z/p^k\mathbf Z)[X]/(F_{i,k}(X)),
$$
where $F_{i,k}(X)$ means $F_i(X) \bmod p^k$.  So for each $k \geq 1$, the rings $(\mathbf Z/p^k\mathbf Z)[X]/(F_{i,k}(X))$ for all $i$ are isomorphic, which is what you wanted to show.

Ultimately, what this argument relies on is that for two monic $F(X)$ and $G(X)$ in $\mathbf Z_p[X]$ of the same degree $d$ that are both irreducible mod $p$, the rings $\mathbf Z_p[X]/(F(X))$ and $\mathbf Z_p[X]/(G(X))$ are isomorphic because they are each isomorphic to the ring of integers of the degree-$d$ unramified extension of $\mathbf Q_p$.  This is related to the similar-looking fact that roots of two irreducibles of the same degree in $\mathbf F_p[X]$ generate the same field: all finite fields of the same size are isomorphic.

**Remark**.  The argument above works if the $m$th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_m(X)$ is replaced by a polynomial that is monic irreducible in $\mathbf Z[X]$ and a root of it generates a Galois extension of $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: Thank you. I do know about the $p$-adics, but need to read about (un)ramified extensions to fully understand your answer.